# Gremlin, filter according to different properties of the same vertex

Tags: gremlin

I have vertices which have two integer properties (int1 and int2). I simply want to select all vertices where int1 is greater than int2.

I already know about this way of doing it,

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').as('a')
   .where('a',gt('a')).by('age').by('k').valueMap('age','k')
```

but I need another way that works with older versions. This gremlin syntax needs Tinkerpop 3.2.4.

Comment: Which gremlin version are you running?

Comment: I don't know since I just have the API. May you please let me know of whatever syntax you know ?

Comment: Your traversal should work just fine in 3.2.4. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: "but I need another way that works with older versions", I need syntax that works for versions older than 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, the traversal should work in 3.2.4. But anyway, here's another way of doing it:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').
  sack(assign).by('age').
  sack(minus).by('k').
  filter(sack().is(gt(0))).
  valueMap('age','k')
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thanks